# How to add textbox value in listview control without database in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Suppose at first i insert data from textbox,combox into listview one by one and  then save data my table in database table.......

Note:Data value insert in listview from textbox without database.

And how can i do that

Comment: Have you tried anything? show us some code/effort.

Comment: let me know if i got it right, you want to insert the data into a list in your memory and then lets say by clicking on save button all the data transfer to the database table right ?